# Unity c# building game but not exe

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

So i know it sounds weird and the title is doesn't that much understandable so let me explain this first to you guys:

I have a unity virtual reality game which i build a couple of weeks now . And i uses a Leap motion device for my game and built it as an OPENVR supported on build setting. So i uses some 3rd party softwares like TrinusVR and SteamVR so that it will become a Virtual Reality even if it not built in .apk file . So when i try my game it was so very laggy(which is in my unity i've got only 50-100 draw calls and 30fps) and also it was jittery.

So i've come up with a solution . Using unity remote 5 it wasn't laggy and jittery but the problem is if i go spread my game out they can edit and mess up with my unity program .

So my question is how can i possibly make my unity project not editable when they open it on unity . Or is there any 3rd party software that i can try.

By the way i tried VRriftcat and SteamVr but still it was jittery and laggy.

Sorry for that long message. Hope someone give me some ideas .

EDIT: If i want to release this one then i'm having a problem in VRridge software and SteamVR.

The photo below shows my game.exe in my laptop using SteamVR and VRidge
[image: See photo please]

and my Vridge software on my laptop is connected already on my VRidge APK on my phone. The problem occurs here now.

It my game doesn't render on my phone.

[image: See image here please.]

Help me guys . I tried your solution earlier so i tried it again and this happened

Comment: Unity Remote 5 is for debugging purposes, you can't release a game with it... I suggest you optimize your game if the frames are dropping. Check out the Unity Profiler!

Comment: Would have thought this is off topic as it doesn't relate to programming IMHO.

Comment: Who can edit what in your built game? I don't understand what you mean by *"if i go spread my game out they can edit and mess up with my unity program"* - are you planning on distributing the game in source form?

Comment: @UnholySheep something like that sir . Leap motion doesn't support fully on mobile yet as i know. that i was i'm finding ways.

Comment: @JamesHughes Im sorry sir . Just curious if i can find some alternative ways.

Comment: @Fredrik the frame rates aren't dropping sir i already done tons of optimization like Group Lod, Cullings, Customize Shaders etc.

Comment: Well you can't run a game in "source mode" on mobile (and neither should you), so if Leap Motion doesn't support mobile you won't be able to run your game there anyway.

Comment: @TheGinxx009, I appreciate the manners, but there's no need to apologise or call anyone sir. In all honesty, what you're asking is not what unity remote is designed for and this is the good old XY Problem... Optimise your game, that will solve your issue.

Comment: @UnholySheep so do you have any 3rd party softwares that i can try . So that my pc games turns into VR game

Comment: @JamesHughes . So how can i turn my pc game into vr game sir or is there any other way to implement leap motion to mobile

Comment: If Leap Motion is the issue, try to address that - perhaps there's an alternative that supports mobile!

Comment: You almost always have to design a game to be a vr game from the ground up! Otherwise the experience is likely to be pretty awful.

Comment: Back to basics here - 1) No one can edit your built game 2) Running it with Unity remote WILL be very laggy.